# rustc - couldn't find required command: "c++"

Tags: rust

I followed [this guide](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/building/how-to-build-and-run.html) for building `rustc` and got the error:

```bash
-> % ./x.py check
Building rustbuild
    Finished dev [unoptimized] target(s) in 0.94s
thread 'main' panicked at '

couldn't find required command: "c++"

', sanity.rs:59:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Build completed unsuccessfully in 0:00:03
```

I see this line in [prerequisites](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/building/prerequisites.html#dependencies):

> g++ 5.1 or later, clang++ 3.5 or later, or MSVC 2017 or later.

But it doesn't explain how to install the command `c++` into system.

I got this error on Rocky Linux 8, but I think this may happens for CentOS   too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [guide](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/install-gcc-on-rocky-linux/) helped me.

TLDR - for install `c++` command into Rocky Linux you need this steps:

1. `sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools"`
2. `sudo dnf install gcc-c++`
3. `c++ -v` - should show version